# Why can't I iterate through a new column in my data frame?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, dataframe, iteration

I have created a data frame of prices, moving averages and now the column 'maX' which highlights when 2 moving averages cross;

```
             OPEN   HIGH    LOW   LAST     ma5     ma8  ma21  maX
Date                                                             
11/23/2009  88.84  89.19  88.58  88.97     NaN     NaN   NaN  0.0
11/24/2009  88.97  89.07  88.36  88.50     NaN     NaN   NaN  0.0
11/25/2009  88.50  88.63  87.22  87.35     NaN     NaN   NaN  0.0
11/26/2009  87.35  87.48  86.30  86.59     NaN     NaN   NaN  0.0
11/27/2009  86.59  87.02  84.83  86.53  87.588     NaN   NaN  0.0
11/30/2009  87.17  87.17  85.87  86.41  87.076     NaN   NaN  0.0
12/1/2009   86.41  87.53  86.17  86.68  86.712     NaN   NaN  0.0
12/2/2009   86.68  87.49  86.59  87.39  86.720  87.302   NaN  0.0
12/3/2009   87.39  88.48  87.32  88.26  87.054  87.214   NaN  0.0
12/4/2009   88.26  90.77  88.00  90.56  87.860  87.471   NaN  0.0
```

However why am I unable to iterate through he new column? my code;

```
Buy = [0,]
maXLast = [0]
for i in maX[1:]: 
    if i == 1 and maXLast == 0:
        Buy.append(1)
    elif i == 1 and maX == -1:
        Buy.append(0)
    else:
        Buy.append(0)
    maXLast = i

print(Buy)       
Entry = pd.DataFrame(Buy,index = dfmas.index).astype('float') 
Entry.columns = ['Buy']
print(Entry)
```

However why does my code just return [0,0] for 'Buy' and not a 1850 float list.

So why does 'Enter' return;

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (1, 1850)    ???
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use for-loops with Pandas.  Instead, do it the vectorized way, which will be about a thousand times faster:

```
import numpy as np
Buy = np.where(maX == 1, 1, 0)
```

Something like that anyway--you may need to tweak the condition in [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).